# Counting subsets with given sizes of a set

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

Given a set C with n elements (duplicates allowed) and a partition P of n
P = {i1, i2, ... / i1+i2+... = n}
how many different decompositions of C in subsets of size i1, i2, ... are there ?

Example :

```
C = {2 2 2 3}

P = {2 2}
C = {2 2} U {2 3}

P = {1 1 2}
C = {2} U {2} U {2 3}
C = {2} U {3} U {2 2}

P = {1 3}
C = {2} U {2 2 3}
C = {3} U {2 2 2}
```

I have a solution, but it is inefficient when C has more than a dozen of elements.
Thanks in advance
*Philippe*

Comment: The question is how many ? or do you need to find them ?

Comment: My solution requires to list the decompositions. I just want to enumerate them. I generate all the permutations of C, then stores all decompositions in a table and count the distinct ones.

Comment: This question might be better placed at math.stackexchange.com with tag: "enumerative combinatorics"

Comment: @PhilippeC: if you allow duplicates in `C`, then it should be a **list**, not a **set**

Comment: @MarcoS: it's neither a set nor a list, it's called **multiset**.

Comment: @ypercube: I guess you're right, because a **list** would imply ordering

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the order of decomposition does not matter to you makes it much harder.  That is, you are viewing `{2 2} U {2 3}` as the same as `{2 3} U {2 2}`.  Still I have an algorithm that is better than what you have, but is not great.

Let me start it with a realistically complicated example.  Our set will be `A B C D E F F F F G G G G`.  The partition will be `1 1 1 1 2 2 5`.

My first simplification will be to represent the information we care about in the set with the data structure `[[2, 4], [5, 1]]`, meaning 2 elements are repeated 4 times, and 5 are repeated once.

My second apparent complication will be to represent the partition with `[[5, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [4, 1, 1]`.   The pattern may not be obvious.  Each entry is of the form `[size, count, frequency]`.  So the one distinct instance of 2 partitions of size 2 turn into `[2, 2, 1]`.  We're not using frequency yet, but it is counting distinguishable piles of the same size and commonness.

Now we're going to recurse as follows.  We'll take the most common element, and find all of the ways to use it up.  So in our case we take one of the piles of size 4, and find that we can divide it as follows, rearranging each remaining partition strategy in lexicographic order:

1. `[4]` leaving `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[2, 2, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`.
2. `[3, [1, 0], 0]` leaving `[[2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[2, 1, 2], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1]`.  (Note that we're now using frequency.)
3. `[3, 0, 1]` leaving `[[2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]] = [[2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]]`
4. `[2, [2, 0], 0]` leaving `[[3, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[3, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1]]`
5. `[2, [1, 1], 0]` leaving `[[3, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[3, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 2, 1]]`
6. `[2, [1, 0], [1]]` leaving `[[3, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]] = [[3, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`
7. `[2, 0, [1, 1]]` leaving `[[3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]] = [[3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]]1
8. `[1, [2, 1]]` leaving `[[4, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[4, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`
9. `[1, [2, 0], [1]]` leaving `[[4, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]] = [[4, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]]`
10. `[1, [1, 0], [1, 1]]` leaving `[[4, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]] = [[4, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`
11. `[1, 0, [1, 1, 1]]` leaving `[[4, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [0, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1]] = [[4, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`
12. `[0, [2, 2]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 4, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1], [1, 4, 1]]`
13. `[0, [2, 1], [1]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1], [1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1]]`
14. `[0, [2, 0], [1, 1]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]`
15. `[0, [1, 1], [1, 1]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1,], [1, 2, 2]]`
16. `[0, [1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [0, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2]]`
17. `[0, 0, [1, 1, 1, 1]]` leaving `[[5, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [0, 4, 1]] = [[5, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1]]`

Now each of those subproblems can be solved recursively.  This may feel like we're on the way to constructing them all, but we aren't, because we [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the recursive steps.  It turns out that there are a lot of ways that the first two groups of 8 can wind up with the same 5 left overs.  With memoization we don't need to repeatedly recalculate those solutions.

That said, we'll do better.  Groups of 12 elements should not pose a problem.  But we're not doing *that* much better.  I wouldn't be surprised if it starts breaking down somewhere around groups of 30 or so elements with interesting sets of partitions.  (I haven't coded it.  It may be fine at 30 and break down at 50.  I don't know where it will break down.  But given that you're iterating over sets of partitions, at some fairly small point it *will* break down.)

Comment: I'll need some time to try your solution (probably not until next week-end)... I'll let you know how faster your solution is compared to mine. Thank a lot.

Comment: @PhilippeC: When you do, be sure to try variations.  Some back of the envelope reasoning has suggested to me that it might be good to start with the small piles of elements rather than the large piles.  It is also possible to start trying to fill in parts of the partition instead of use up piles.

Answer (score 0):

All partitions can be found in 2 stages.

First: from `P` make new ordered partition of n, `P_S={P_i1, P_i2, ..., P_ip}`, summing identical i's.

```
P = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5}
P_S = (4, 4, 5)
```

Make partitions `{C_i1, C_i2, ..., C_ip}` of `C` with respect to `P_S`. Note, `C_ix` is multi-set like `C`. It is partitioning C into multi-sets by sizes of final partitions.

Second: for each `{C_i1, C_i2, ..., C_ip}` and for each `ix, x={1,2,...,p}` find number of partitions of `C_ix` into `t` (number of `ix's` in `P`) sets with `ix` elements. Call this number `N(C_ix,ix,t)`.

Total number of partitions is:

```
sum by all {C_i1, C_i2, ..., C_ip} ( product N(C_ix,ix,t) ix={1,2,...,p} )
```

First part can be done recursively quite simple. Second is more complicated. Partition of multi-set `M` into `n` parts with `k` elements is same as finding all partially sorted list with elements from `M`. Partially order list is of type:

```
a_1_1, a_1_2, ..., a_1_k, a_2_1, a_2_2, ..., a_2_k, ....
```

Where `a_i_x <= a_i_y` if `x < y` and `(a_x_1, a_x_2, ..., a_x_k) lexicographic <= (a_y_1, a_y_2, ..., a_y_k)` if `x < y`. With these 2 conditions it is possible to create all partition from `N(C_ix,ix,t)` recursively.

For some cases `N(C_ix,ix,t)` is easy to calculate. Define `|C_ix|` as number of different elements in multi-set `C_ix`.

```
if t = 1 than 1
if |C_ix| = 1 than 1
if |C_ix| = 2 than (let m=minimal number of occurrences of elements in C_ix) floor(m/2) + 1
 in general if |C_ix| = 2 than partition of m in numbers <= t.
```